# Azure AD | Service to service auth setup

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to use Azure AD to lock down access to authenticated users.  I'm hoping someone could direct me to a setup that might fit the need here (and I feel like I must be overlooking the solution...).

We have an application that will expose various endpoints to be called by other teams in the organization.  Nearly all of the consumers will be other user-less applications. (also none of these are Azure hosted/deployed services)

For auditing purposes, one of the requirements is the need to know what user (service) is calling any given endpoint.

Essentially, in the following:

[image]

We would need to be able to have Consumer 1 call My API, Consumer 2 call My API , and be able to determine inside of My API who the current consumer is.

I know with the client credentials flow, we could create multiple secrets and provide one to each consumer.  However from the generated token, it appears that these are essentially both tokens on behalf of the Service Principal (so no way to know who the call is coming from).

I'd also looked into the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), but I think am running into issue since we are using ADFS with our on prem AD servers.

Any easy button I'm overlooking? (fingerscrossed)

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to share my humble opinions here.

Firstly, access token is used for calling api which contains the information that if the token has correct scoped for the target api. And Id token contains the user informaion.

So if the Consumer1 and Consumer2 are on behalf of application itself, then it can't add user information within the access token and there's no id token for it. In this scenario, I think what you can do is adding an identifier into the request along with the access token, then your api application can both check if the token is illegal and which Consumer sends this request. This scenario used client credential flow to generate access token.

If the Consumer1 and Consumer2 are on behalf of users, or they are application but the request calling your api application can get the current user information, then you may send id token along with access token, or just send the user id as an identifier. This scenario may need users to sign in, so maybe auth code flow is better then credential flow.